# Elegant way from map to csv scala (flatten a map)

Tags: scala, dictionary, flatmap

I have a map that looks like this :

```
val m1 = Map(IND1 -> List((IND1,List((AA,11), (BB,12)))), 
  IND2  ->List((IND1,List((AA,42), (BB,80)))))
```

The result format is :

```
List((IND1,11,12),(IND2,42,80))
```

I tried using `flatMap` on the values but it is not working and the only way I can get it to work is:

```
m1.mapValues(x => x.head._2).map(x =>(x._1,x._2(0)._2,x._2(1)._2))
```

This gives me the right format but I know there must be a better and more elegant way. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **pattern match/ deconstruct** on value of a `Map` as below,

```
val m1 = Map(
  "IND1" -> List(
    ("IND1", List(("AA", 11), ("BB", 12)))
    //(k,    (first        :: second  :: Nil)
  ),
  "IND2" -> List(
    ("IND1", List(("AA", 42), ("BB", 80)))
    //(k,    (first        :: second  :: Nil)
  )
)

val results = m1.map {
  case (key, ((k, (f :: s :: Nil)) :: Nil)) =>
    (key, f._2, s._2)
}

println(results) // List((IND1,11,12), (IND2,42,80))
```

**You can go further and deconstruct `f`, and `s` as well as tuples,**

```
val results = m1.map {
  case (key, (_, (_, first) :: (_, second) :: Nil) :: Nil) =>
    (key, first, second)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for {
    (k, valuesList)   <- m1
    (_, values)       <- valuesList
    v1::v2::Nil = values.map(_._2)
} yield (k, v1, v2)
```